# ActiveModel::Serializer sort and serialize

Tags: ruby, sorting, activerecord, serialization, model

for example i have two activeRecord models:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :article_poster
end
```

and

```
class ArticlePoster < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

In some controller:

```
CustomSerializer.new(articles)
```

CustomSerializer:

```
class CustomSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
end
```

I have 4 articles, with poster and without it. 
For example: 
1st article poster present
2nd article poster NOT present
3rd article poster present
4th article poster present

I need articles in order by poster presence: 1,3,4,2.
What is the best way to implement it in `CustomSerializer` or in `Article` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is:

```
class CustomSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  def initialize(resources, options = {})
    resources = sort(resources) 
    super(resources, options)
  end

  def sort(resources)
    top = []
    regular = []
    resources.each do |article|
      if article.poster
        top << article 
      else
        regular << article
      end
    end
    resources = top + regular
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using sql

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :article_poster

  scope :join_article_posters, -> {
    joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN article_posters ON article_posters.article_id = article.id') }
  }

  scope :posters_first -> { join_article_posters.order(article_posters: { id: :desc }) }
end
```

*posters_first may be done better differently depending on your database*

---

```
CustomSerializer.new(articles.posters_first)
```

Comment: Your answer  is correct. But now i have new requirements to my code. For example: in first 3 places should be articles with posters and further by original order. Also its not always posible to call models method in my project. In some parts of code i already have list of articles and must sort them there, in that place. There is no need to send request to DB again.  Thats why sort in `CustomSerializer` is preferable in this case.

Comment: @sig Do sorting in serializer is a rather unintuitive hack. However, if you work on a project alone, it doesn't matter. At least change your code to `CustomSerializer.new(articles.includes(:poster)) `, that way you'll avoid N+1

Comment: sometimes when you work at project not alone you have to sacrifice intuitiveness. Because some things don't depend from you.